# htmlspecialchar to multiple variables

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

I was wondering if there's a simpler way of doing this

```
$admsquarecmail = @$_POST['squarecmail'];
$admsquarecmail = htmlspecialchars($admsquarecmail, ENT_COMPAT);

$admsquarecsubject = @$_POST['squarecsubject'];
$admsquarecsubject = htmlspecialchars($admsquarecsubject, ENT_COMPAT);

$admsquarectymessage = @$_POST['squarectymessage'];
$admsquarectymessage = htmlspecialchars($admsquarectymessage, ENT_COMPAT);

$admsquarecontagain = @$_POST['squarecontagain'];
$admsquarecontagain = htmlspecialchars($admsquarecontagain, ENT_COMPAT);
```

The idea is not to type

```
htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_COMPAT);
```

every time a variable is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1:

You may apply [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to all elements of `$_POST` with [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$arr = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $_POST, array_fill(0, sizeof($_POST), ENT_COMPAT));
```

Then:

```
$admsquarecmail = isset($arr['squarecmail']) ? $arr['squarecmail'] : "";
$admsquarecsubject = isset($arr['squarecsubject']) ? $arr['squarecsubject'] : "";
$admsquarectymessage = isset($arr['squarectymessage']) ? $arr['squarectymessage'] : "";
```

...and so on.

### Method 2:

You may apply [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to the elements of `$_POST` one by one. In this method you don’t need an array apart from `$_POST` itself:

```
$admsquarecmail = isset($_POST['squarecmail']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['squarecmail'], ENT_COMPAT) : "";
$admsquarecsubject = isset($_POST['squarecsubject']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['squarecsubject'], ENT_COMPAT) : "";
$admsquarectymessage = isset($_POST['squarectymessage']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['squarectymessage'], ENT_COMPAT) : "";
```

...and so on.

### Method 3:

You may create a small function like the following:

```
function obtain_POST_value($key){
if(array_key_exists($key, $_POST)) return htmlspecialchars($_POST[$key], ENT_COMPAT);
return "";
}
```

Then:

```
$admsquarecmail = obtain_POST_value('squarecmail');
$admsquarecsubject = obtain_POST_value('squarecsubject');
$admsquarectymessage = obtain_POST_value('squarectymessage');
```

...and so on.

Comment: Assigning to `$_POST` like this isn't a good idea because you're muddying up your data, likely way too early.

Comment: Method 3 was exactly what I was looking for. 
Thank you very much.